# How can I automatically search for what my HPPG is and mutliply it by a formula

Tags: excel

Hey in my model I have a a query for the HT Goal Expectancy

```
=SUM(B12*E13*R25)
```

**I want to include the HPPG or the APPG in this calculation without having to manually do it every time.** In a query above I use a function to find values from the table on the right to calculate things like average goals

```
=IFERROR((INDEX(R:R,MATCH($A4,M:M,0)) +
 INDEX(S:S,MATCH($A4,M:M,0)))/(INDEX(N:N,MATCH($A4,M:M,0))),"False")
```

**Is there a way that I can search for the HPPG and then multiply it by the other cells?**

```
=SUM(B12*E13*R25)
```

[image: My model]

Comment: If I counted correctly you can find the HPPG for the first team by using `=INDEX(AK:AK,MATCH($A4,M:M,0))` and then for the second team use: `=INDEX(AK:AK,MATCH($A5,M:M,0))`

Comment: how can I multiply the result of that by the other sum?

Comment: Do you mean this? `=SUM(B12*E13*R25)*INDEX(AK:AK,MATCH($A4,M:M,0)`